# Алло, аллё или алле?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Разные люди говорит по-разному, но чаще всего все-таки "алло". А есть ли какая норма для этого слова?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Правильное обращение по телефону - [алё], а правильное написание этого слова - алло.

[Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/22-spravka/letters/98-rubric-70)

То же самое говорит и Орфоэпический словарь русского языка: Произношение, ударение, грамматические формы / Под ред. Р.И. Аванесова (1983).

Но Каленчук М.С., Касаткина Р.Ф. в "Словаре трудностей русского произношения" (1997) дают допустимым вариантом и [ало].

В общем, строго по норме *алло* [ал'о], но ничего страшного, если и [ало].

Answer (score 2):

Аллё - (разг.), то же, что алло. Литературная норма только алло [алё]. В словаре РАН под редакцией Лопатина только алло.

Comment: Это у вас Ё так напечатано? Тогда - да. 
Потому что "алле/але" - это уже совсем другое междометие.

Comment: "Литературная норма только алло" - почему такая категоричность?

Comment: По словарю. Другое дело, модно ли вообще говорить о норме в подобных случаях...

Comment: Ну вот, например, в Современном толковом словаре русского языка Ефремовой Т.Ф. 2000 г. слово "алё" присутствует.

Answer (score 0):

Да, разговор о норме в данном случае размыт. Само слово носит разговорный характер, фонетической нормы для него нет. Употребление разных форм в литературе может носить разве что стилистическую окраску.

Comment: Вот поэтому я чаще говорю "слушаю" :)